# jquery mobile trigger create enchances some elements but not all

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I think this may be a bug in Jquery Mobile, but it could also be user error (mine).

For a jquery mobile page, I am manually calling `$(..).trigger("create")` after loading in some html asynchronously.  I am finding an odd - to me anyway - behaviour, which is that  `<input>`s of type text on the loaded html are *not* enhanced to have JQM's styling, whereas `<input>s` that are of type button are.

Here's a stripped-down version that replicates the problem.  Basically, a page loads and injects `foo.html.`  Part of `foo.html` is a placeholder div that is subsequently loaded and injected with `bar.html.`  `bar.html` contains a link that opens a popup.  When it's clicked and the popup opens, buttons are styled correctly; inputs are not.

Note:  I call `trigger("create")` on the parent of the injected content.

Further note:  calling `trigger("create")` on the *grandparent* of where `bar.html` is injected makes everything be styled correctly, including inputs on the popup.  See below for code.

in the body of my basic html page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="grandparent" data-theme="a">
<h3>A very basic page</h3>
</div>
```

the script in that page's head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $(document).ready(function() {      
    var path = "pathToFiles/";
    $("#grandparent").load(path + "foo.html", null, function() {
      $("#grandparent").trigger("create");

      //now load bar
      $("#bar_placeholder").load(path + "bar.html", null, function() {

        /*this does NOT enhance text <input> on popup*/
        $("#bar_placeholder").trigger("create");

        /*this DOES enhance text <input> on popup*/
        //$("#grandparent").trigger("create");

      });            
    });    
  });  
</script>
```

here is foo.html

```
<div data-role="content" id="foo">
  <h3>Foo before placeholder...</h3>

  <div id="bar_placeholder" data-role="content"></div>

  <h3>...foo after placeholder</h3>

  <label for="foo_input" class="ui-hidden-accessible">foo input IS enhanced:</label>
  <input id="foo_input" value="" placeholder="i AM enhanced" data-theme="a" type="text" />


  <input type="button" id="foo_button" value="Foo Button"/>

</div>
```

and here is bar.html:

```
<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" data-theme="a" data-transition="pop">bar popup button</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <h3>Bar header</h3>              

    <label for="bar_input" class="ui-hidden-accessible">bar text input NOT enhanced</label>
    <input name="bar_input" id="bar_input" placeholder="i am NOT enhanced" data-theme="a" type="text"/>

    <input type="button" data-theme="a" value="bar button"/>    

</div>
```

Comment: Can you try $("#bar_placeholder").trigger("pagecreate"); , I dont think this will solve this problem, but if this is a bug it would be good to know if pagecreate is also affected.

Comment: @Gajotres - replacing `$("#bar_placeholder").trigger("create");` with "pagecreate" causes an error to be thrown ("n.data("page") is undefined).  I assume that's because bar_placeholder is a content div, not a page?  using instead `$("#grandparent").trigger("pagecreate");` causes all enhancements to work as expected

Comment: Also, removing the popup features of bar.html (leaving just a button and a text input) causes it to render correctly.  Which seems to indicate that the popup itself has some role in the issue...